# C# close other process when its not responding

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a program that will relaunch another program when it's not responding. When the monitored program not responding a system message box will pop up and display

```
 -> Check online for a solution or close the program
 -> Close the program
 -> Debug the program
```

and a windows event will be written into windows event log. I add a trigger to this windows event that will run the relaunch program. It will kill the not responding program then relaunch it. But I found neither the .kill() nor the .CloseMainWindow() can close the not responding program and the system dialog. Is there a way to kill a not responding program?
Belows are my codes:

```
           Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(app_name);

            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                bool havingMainWindowHandle = false;
                if (p.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
                    havingMainWindowHandle = false;
                    writeLog(p.ProcessName + " don't have MainWindowHandle");
                } else {
                    havingMainWindowHandle = true;
                    writeLog(p.ProcessName + " status:" + p.Responding.ToString());
                }

                p.WaitForExit(1000);
                if (havingMainWindowHandle)
                {
                    p.CloseMainWindow();
                    p.Close();
                } else
                {
                    writeLog(app_name + " is terminated by .kill() API");
                    p.Kill(); //but function kill() can't terminate the not responding program 
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Process my_otherprogram = new Process();
            my_otherprogram.StartInfo.FileName = app_path;       
            my_otherprogram.Start();
```

Comment: What does "not responding" mean? Are you referring to how windows states that a program in not responding? If so, you have to understand that all that means is that the ui thread has not returned control to windows within a set amount of time.

Comment: The "not responding" here means the program encounter a problem that a system dialog popup; User can only choose between "Check online for a solution or close the program", "Close the program", "Debug the program". And in such case, I found both .kill() and the .CloseMainWindow() can't close the "not responding" AP and let the system dialog dismissed. I'm looking for the other solution to close the "not responding"(about to crashing) AP.

Comment: And I found even the "taskkill /im myprocess.exe /f" can't delete the "not responding"(about to crash) AP. It would occur error: "Access is denied".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly - to understand what 'Not Responding' means.

It does not mean your application has crashed.
It means that the UI thread that the application runs on, is busy.
This could mean that the developer of that application has chosen to put a large amount of work or a very lengthy loop into the UI thread, instead of implementing it on another thread.

All of these will result in 'Not Responding' for the duration of the work load, until the UI thread is freed up for UI display/rendering.

Typically, the 3 options you get:

> -> Check online for a solution or close the program
>   -> Close the program
>   -> Debug the program

Appear when Windows detects you trying to interact with that 'Not Responding' application. 
Essentially, it detects that you want to interact with the UI, but the UI is not available at the moment.
This does NOT mean that the UI will never become available, and does NOT mean that the application has definitely crashed.
It just means that the UI is not available to take requests at that exact moment. Waiting 10 seconds or 10 minutes may even allow it to fix itself.

Now, in terms of why you may not be able to kill the process.
The comment posted above where you get 'Access Denied' when trying task kill, suggests the process that is running that you wish to terminate, may be running with elevated permissions.

As a rule of thumb, an application that is running as Administrator or LOCAL SERVICE, cannot be terminated by someone or something that has less permissions.

If you want to test this theory out, run your command prompt as Administrator, and see if the task kill gives the same result.

p.Kill(); should be able to kill all processes, assuming the calling application has enough elevated permissions to do so.

It should be noted however, that p.Kill will terminate an application in a very abrupt manner, not letting threads terminate cleanly - E.g Database data may be left in an intermediate state, files may be corrupted if they are still open etc.

If you own the application that is experiencing the 'Not Responding' state and you have the source code of the application, the ideal solution would be to migrate the heavy lifting of the application onto a background thread.

This can be as simple as

```
Thread tworker = new Thread(()=>WorkThread(arg1,arg2,arg3));
tworker.IsBackground= true;
tworker.Start();
```

This would shift the execution of your WorkThread onto a background thread, which leaves your UI thread nice and clean.
Of course - you could also design the methods to be asynchronous and use Tasks.